# How can I use private or public keyword in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webstorm

I need to specify my properties as private or public in TypeScript files (`tsx`/`ts` files), but unfortunately I'm getting compilation error.

It is **React project** using **TypeScript** files.

IDE is **WebStorm 2021.3**.

**TypeScript** version is **4.5.4**.

[image: Compilation error]

I have tried to change some properties in `tsconfig.json` files, but with no success.

```
export class Example{
  private id: number;
  private name: string;

  constructor(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

This is the sample code I created just for this purpose. Other than this, I've just imported this class into `app.js` file and it throws the above compilation error.

This is the TypeScript configuration:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you install typescript? Because the 'private' modifier can only be used in TypeScript files.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have typescript 4.5.4 version installed. @MWO

Comment: provide `tsconfig.json` file as well. Also can you try to convert your app.js file into app.ts.

Comment: tsconfig.json is now included in description @ShubhamWaje

Answer (score 0):

you must specified the type of the Fields

```
export  class Exemple{
#id:number()
public name:string
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but without success.

Comment: i hope this help  you https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming you are fairly new to TS/JS - unless something is exported from a file it is private to the file.

Try to avoid classes, try to create using es6 syntax - they are much easier to work with, like so;

```
const exampleFunction = (param: String): string => {
  return param;
}

export default exampleFunction;
```

Or if you must use classes.

```
class Point {
  x: number
  y: number
  static instances = 0
  constructor(x: number, y: number) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }
}
```

Useful cheatsheet here https://devhints.io/typescript

Comment: There is more complex task behind the scene where I need to work with classes and private keywords, but I tried to simplify it, just for the purpose of asking the question. I tried to use private keyword in .ts and .tsx files but I always get this compilation error. I'm starting to think it is because of some WebStorm setting or something like that.

Comment: try using and underline? i.e. _name - its expected private props in some places. Get onto vscode? You look to be doing it right, so am not sure what up - have a read of this? https://coryrylan.com/blog/private-methods-and-properties-in-typescript-classes#typescript-constructor-assignment

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `tsconfig.json` you've provided was automatically generated, so that's not the cause of the issue.

Following is the valid code in typescript.

```
export class Example {
  private id: number;
  private name: string;

  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    console.log(`Example ${this.id} created with name ${this.name}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I actually wrote, but I still get compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with renaming `app.js` to `app.tsx`.